# How to run a server-client application in JAVA

Tags: java, server, client

I am trying to run the following code by first running the chatserver file and then the chatclient file.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class  chatserver
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(2000);
        Socket sk=ss.accept();
        BufferedReader cin=newBufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));
        PrintStream cout=new PrintStream(sk.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader stdin=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s;
        while (  true )
        {
            s=cin.readLine();
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("END"))
            {
                cout.println("BYE");
                    break;
              }
            System. out.print("Client : "+s+"\n");
            System.out.print("Server : ");
            s=stdin.readLine();
            cout.println(s);
        }
        ss.close();
        sk.close();
        cin.close();
        cout.close();
        stdin.close();
    }
}

public class  chatclient
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Socket sk=new Socket("192.168.0.19",2000);
        BufferedReader sin=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));
        PrintStream sout=new PrintStream(sk.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader stdin=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s;
        while (  true )
        {
            System.out.print("Client : ");
            s=stdin.readLine();
            sout.println(s);
            s=sin.readLine();
            System.out.print("Server : "+s+"\n");
            if ( s.equalsIgnoreCase("BYE") )
               break;
        }
         sk.close();
         sin.close();
         sout.close();
        stdin.close();
    }
}
```

But it is not working. What are the correct procedure/steps to run a this kind of application?

Running the server file gives the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
    at javaapplication1.chatserver.main(chatserver.java:19)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Address already in use means some program is already listening on port 2000 (most likely the same program that you didn't shutdown properly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Address already in use` means some program is already listening on port 2000 (most likely the same program that you didn't shutdown properly).

Try out a different port.

You may use the `netstat` command on your command line to see which ports are currently in use.

Answer (score 1):

**Address already in use: JVM_Bind**

Java application is trying to connect on port 2000 but that port is already used by some other process and `JVM` Bind to that particular port 2000, is failed. Now to fix this error you need to find out which process is listening of port 2000

*Windows users:*

1. In Command Prompt, send command "netstat -ao". You can get network information for all processes.
2. Find out the one using port 2000, get the PID.
3. Find out the process with the PID you just got from windows task manager and shut it down. (By default the Task Manager doesn't show the PID. You have to add it from the menu View | Select columns)
4. Restart Server.
5. Restart the application you've just shutdown.

*Unix users:*

Most Unix systems have the built-in fuser command that returns the process which is engaging a port:

```
fuser -v -n (tcp | udp) <port#>
```

but if you can not kill that process than you need to change your web-server configuration or eclipse configuration to listen on different port. In case of tomcat you can change it on connector section of `server.xml` and in case of eclipse you can see here setting up Eclipse for Java remote debugging.

Comment: MS-DOS is an operating system. The Windows command prompt is an interface that looks like MS-DOS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your working example:

// Server

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

public Server() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("Server started");
    ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(8888);
    System.out.println("Server waiting for connection");
    Socket sk=ss.accept();
    System.out.println("Server Connected");
    BufferedReader cin=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));
    PrintStream cout=new PrintStream(sk.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader stdin=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s;
    while (  true )
    {
        s=cin.readLine();
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("END"))
        {
            cout.println("BYE");
                break;
          }
        System. out.print("Client : "+s+"\n");
        System.out.print("Server : ");
        s=stdin.readLine();
        cout.println(s);
    }
    ss.close();
    sk.close();
    cin.close();
    cout.close();
    stdin.close();
}

}
```

// Client

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

public Client() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("Client started");
    Socket sk=new Socket("localhost",8888);
    System.out.println("Client Connected");
    BufferedReader sin=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));
    PrintStream sout=new PrintStream(sk.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader stdin=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s;
    while (  true )
    {
        System.out.print("Client : ");
        s=stdin.readLine();
        sout.println(s);
        s=sin.readLine();
        System.out.print("Server : "+s+"\n");
        if ( s.equalsIgnoreCase("BYE") )
           break;
    }
     sk.close();
     sin.close();
     sout.close();
    stdin.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the port number you are using to run your application.
For more check this link- http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/solving-javanetbindexception-address-already-in-use-jvmbind

Answer (score 0):

your port 2000 is already in use by another process.

try using the netstat command on your commandline to see which port are in use.

I usually use 5 digit ports like 10999 which is uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same port for both client and server: 2000, that's why starting client fails because only one process can use a socket, so if server takes it then client can't.